# AnyLogic: Look ahead simulation

Tags: decision-tree, anylogic, event-simulation

Is it possible to perform look ahead simulation in AnyLogic?
Specifically:

1. Simulate till time T.
2. Using 2 values of a variable, simulate for both values till T+t in parallel.
3. Evaluate the system state at T+t, choose the value of variable which leads to better performance.
4. Continue simulating from T using the selected value for the variable.

This is the basic functionality I am trying to implement. The variable values can be taken from decision tree, which should not affect the implementation.

Please let me know if someone has done something like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible with some Java code. You may:

1. Pause parent experiment, save snapshot at time T;
2. Create two new experiments from parent experiment;
3. Load snapshots in two new experiments;
4. Continue execution of both experiments till time T + t;
5. Send notification to parent experiment, compare the results, assign the best value and continue simulation.

Some points can be done manually with UI controls or by code, some — by code only.

Comment: I could find the method to be called for pause, save, and load snapshots. Can you please guide me regarding runTillTime() method and communication between two experiments?

Comment: The "Using 2 values of a variable, simulate for both values till T+t in parallel" also means you need to worry about designing your model so that changes to this mid-run are 'clean' (possibly using on-change functionality of AnyLogic parameters to 'chain down' any effects of changing that variable). It may be fine depending on your model functionality.

Comment: @SwapRenushe, run till time T+t: `getEngine().runFast(time() + constant);`. Experiment communication: since you create experiment instance by from another experiment, just save reference to new experiment in parent experiment. You can get its top-level agent and all its members with something like: `((Main)getEngine().getRoot())`